# Difference between authorization in system.web and system.webServer in web.config?

Tags: .net, iis, web-config, config

I am wondering what the difference are between these snippets. Not in regards to the specific contents of the `<authorization>` element, but in regards to the `system.web` and `system.webServer` elements.

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <security>
         <authorization>
            <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
            <add accessType="Allow" users="" roles="Administrators" />
         </authorization>
      </security>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And:

```
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

My theory after research so far is this:

- `system.webServer` configures IIS (starting from IIS 7).
- `system.web` configures ASP.NET.

Will the authorization config applied beneath `system.webServer` be at a "lower" level (IIS), while the auth configured under `system.web` be picked up by the ASP.NET framework, and enforced by it's running code? Will one overwrite the other? Can I use the authorize element under `system.web` on IIS 10 just fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between the system.web and system.webServer. they will not overwrite each other.

The [<system.webServer>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/) element specifies the root element for many of the site-level and application-level configuration settings for Internet Information Services (IIS) 7 in the ApplicationHost.config file, and contains configuration elements that define the settings used by the Web server engine and modules.

The [<system.web>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/web/system-web-element-web-settings) element contains information about how the ASP.NET hosting layer manages process-wide behavior. The system.web element and its child applicationPool element were added to the .NET Framework as of .NET Framework 3.5 SP1. When you run IIS 7.0 or later versions in Integrated mode, this element combination lets you configure how ASP.NET manages threads and how it queues requests when ASP.NET is hosted in an IIS application pool. If you run IIS 7.0 or later versions in Classic or ISAPI mode, these settings are ignored.

You can configure authorization under system.web, and then publish it to iis.

Answer (score 0):

`system.web` is the settings section for IIS6 and older versions

`system.webServer` is the replacement settings section for IIS7 and higher ones

For more information you can also refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb515251(v=vs.140)#the-systemwebserver-section

If the auth portion is not really working, verify if there's anything else missing in the setup:
If is something with Authorization you can check this official documentation: [System.Webserver authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authorization/#setup)

But if is related to the authentication then check this other one:[System.Webserver authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/#configuration-sample)

Comment: On IIS 10 the `system.webServer` auth had no effect, but auth under `system.web` had. Maybe it's because Forms Authentication is set up under `system.web` as well? The `system.web` config works even with the newest IIS versions?

Comment: try checking  your settings on IIS 10, probably something is not well setup that's why it is not properly working there, I updated my answer to include some articles from the official documentation of authorization and authentication